# Is this normal that each list item in Solidjs is mounting on every change?

Tags: solid-js

Is this normal that each list item in Solidjs is mounting on every change?

```
import { Component, createSignal, For } from 'solid-js';

const data = [
  {name: 'Helen'},
  {name: 'Peter'},
  {name: 'Maksim'},
]

const Card: Component = (props: {name: string}) => {
  console.log('card'); // It runs on every click which I'm not expecting 

  return <div>
   <span>Name: </span>
   <span>{props.name}</span>
 </div>
}

export const App: Component = () => {
  const [users, setUsers] = createSignal(data)

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => setUsers(users => users.map(user => ({...user, name: 'Suzy'})))}>Click</button>
      <For  each={users()}>{user => <Card {...user} />}</For>
    </>
  );
};
```

The same happens with createStore.

Answer (score 1):

That is normal because you are updating every list item inside `setUsers` by mapping over items and creating a new object that has the same values. Although you use previous values, you are creating new object.

`For` keeps the reference of an item if the array item does not change. Its internal logic is something like this:

```js
const cache = {};
cache[user] = <Card />
```

Since you are changing every array items, invalidating the cache by throwing away the old key, hence a new item is rendered. When this new item is rendered, `Card` is mounted.

Try this code, in this one we are updating only the first item:

```js
import { Component, createSignal, For } from 'solid-js';
import { render } from 'solid-js/web';

const data = [{ name: 'Helen' }, { name: 'Peter' }, { name: 'Maksim' }];

const Card: Component<{ name: string }> = (props) => {
  console.log(props.name);
  return (
    <div>
      <span>Name: </span>
      <span>{props.name}</span>
    </div>
  );
};

export const App = () => {
  const [users, setUsers] = createSignal(data);

  const handleClick = () =>
    setUsers((users) => [
      ...users.map((val, i) => (i === 0 ? { ...val } : val)),
    ]);

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Click</button>
      <For each={users()}>{(user) => <Card {...user} />}</For>
    </>
  );
};

render(App, document.body);
```